# Paper trail object changes and rails enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I'm working on versioning models in an old project. almost all of the enum's values used in the project are integers. when tracking changes with object_changes the values are displayed as integers, which is not clear to the end user viewing this data.

for example

```
class Article  
    has_paper_trail
   enum status: {draft: 0, published: 1}
end
```

the record is saved with object changes `status :[0,1]`
is there a way either to save or display the status key instead of the value?

Comment: Why are the end users viewing the data unprocessed? Humanizing enums is a view concern - not a model concern.

Comment: you can use Article.statuses.invert[0] to get string names of statuses

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the readable form of the enum value by using the following code.

```rb
version = Article.first.versions.last
version.changeset["status"]
```

To go even further, migrate your data and define your enums for 'status' as follows.

```rb
enum status: {draft: :draft, published: :published}
```

Rails will save the values as strings; therefore, its attribute must have a compatible data type.